# Why is AOP Logging not working in my project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, aop, aspect

I'm wasting a lot of time right now with AOP logging setup.
I don't know why AOP isn't working in my project.
I think I've done all the settings I can.
Please let me know if you guys have a solutions.
Thank you.

- application.java

```java
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.demo.apiservice")
@MapperScan("com.demo.apiservice.mapper")
public class ApiServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
      return builder.sources(ApiServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(ApiServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
       return new CustmizedModelMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    public AopLoggingConfig loggingAspect(){
       return new AopLoggingConfig();
    }
}
```

- build.gradle

  ```
    configurations {
            all {
               exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
            }
    }

    dependencies {
            //implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.5'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.5'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.5.5'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:2.5.5'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.5.5'
        implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.3'
        testImplementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.3'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:2.5.5'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
            implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
            implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.8'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.5'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.5.5'
            implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
            implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.5.5'
            implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.4.2'
            implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.3'
            implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.3'
            implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.3'
            implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'
            implementation 'com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.7'
            implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
            implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
            implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10'
            implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.1'
            implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
            implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
            implementation 'de.mkammerer:argon2-jvm:2.7'
            implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68'
            implementation 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0'
            implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
            implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4'
            implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.6.1.Final'
            implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.6.0'
            compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
        testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
            runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.5.5'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
        testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
            testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.5'
            testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.5.2'
    }
  ```
- AopLoggingComponent.java

  ```
    package com.demo.apiservice.config;

    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    @Aspect
    public class AopLoggingConfig {

        Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(AopLoggingConfig.class);

        static String name = "";

        static String type = "";

        /**
            *   AspectJ is applied only to a specific class/method in package.
            */
        @Around("execution(* com.demo.apiservice.customer.*Controller.*(..))")
        public Object logPrint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            type = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();

            if (type.indexOf("Controller")  -1) {
                name = "Controller  \t:  ";
            }
            else if (type.indexOf("Service")  -1) {
                name = "ServiceImpl  \t:  ";
            }
            else if (type.indexOf("DAO")  -1) {
                name = "DAO  \t\t:  ";
            }
            logger.debug(name + type + ".@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()");
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }
    }
  ```
- controller.java

  ```
    package com.demo.apiservice.customer;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.demo.apiservice.constant.Constants;
    import com.demo.apiservice.customer.service.CustomerService;
    import com.demo.apiservice.customer.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl;
    import com.demo.apiservice.request.CustomerRequest;
    import com.demo.apiservice.request.LoginRequest;
    import com.demo.apiservice.response.GetCustomerResponse;
    import com.demo.apiservice.response.SuccessResponse;
    import com.demo.apiservice.utils.ResponseHandler;

    import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.validation.Valid;

    @Slf4j
    @RestController
    @Api(tags = "Customers APIs")
    @RequestMapping("/apiservice/v1/customers")
    public class CustomerController {

            @Autowired
            private CustomerService customerService;

            @GetMapping
            @ApiOperation(value = "List of Customers API")
            @ApiResponses(value = {
                      @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = Constants.BAD_REQUEST),
                      @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = Constants.ACCESS_DENIED)})
            public ResponseEntity<Object retrieveAll() {
               log.info("Start of CustomerController::retrieveAll method");
               return customerService.retrieveAll();
            }
    }
  ```
- application.yml

  ```
    logging:
      level:
            org:
             springframework.web: DEBUG
             hibernat: DEBUG
            com:
             atoz_develop:
               mybatissample:
                    repository: TRACE

    mybatis:
      mapper-locations: classpath:/mappers/*.xml
      type-aliases-package: com.demo.apiservice.entity
      configuration:
            map-underscore-to-camel-case: 'true'

    debug: 'true'

    spring:
      datasource:
            driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
            username: postgres
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
            platform: postgres
            password: postgres
      jpa:
            generate-ddl: 'false'
            properties:
             hibernate:
               dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
               format_sql: 'true'
            hibernate:
             ddl-auto: update
            show-sql: 'true'
  ```
- stack trace log

  ```
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.992 DEBUG 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                      : GET /apiservice/v1/customers, parameters={}        2021-11-17 16:05:19.992 DEBUG 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.demo.apiservice.customer.CustomerController#retrieveAll()
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.993  INFO 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.l.a.c.CustomerController                        : Start of CustomerController::retrieveAll method
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.993  INFO 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.l.a.c.s.i.CustomerServiceImpl               : Inside of the CustomerServiceImpl :: retrieveAll method
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.996  INFO 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.l.a.c.s.i.CustomerServiceImpl               : End of the CustomerServiceImpl :: retrieveAll method
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.996 DEBUG 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using application/xhtml+xml, given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/xml;charset=UTF-8, text/xml;charset=UTF-8, application/*+xml;charset=UTF-8, application/xml;charset=UTF-8, text/xml;charset=UTF-8, application/*+xml;charset=UTF-8]
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.996 DEBUG 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{data=[Customer(email=test1@test.com, password=null, customerId=null, storeName=eos, firstname=test1 (truncated)...]
    2021-11-17 16:05:19.998 DEBUG 23300 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet                      : Completed 200 OK
  ```

Comment: Does it work if you use `@Around("execution(* com.demo.apiservice.customer. CustomerController.*(..))")`?

Comment: I changed it and test it. But it doesn't work.

Comment: And what about `@Around("execution(* com.demo.apiservice.customer. CustomerController.retrieveAll())")`? Just to check if AOP is working or not. Thanks!

Comment: I did not look at your code in detail yet, but why would you define a `@Bean AopLoggingConfig` factory method, if the aspect is picked up by component scan already? There is no need to manually instantiate it.

Comment: Furthermore, something like `if (type.indexOf("Controller")  -1)` should not even compile, because it is not a boolean expression. Maybe you mean something like `if (type.indexOf("Controller") == -1)`. Please do not post pseudo code here, make sure to test your example after extracting it from your original application and anonymising it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I changed it and test it. it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your aspect is triggered. I added an explicit controller method call in order to check:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ApiServiceApplication.class, args);
    context.getBean(CustomerController.class).retrieveAll();
  }
```

Then I fixed some typos in your code like the one mentioned in my previous comment.

Probably your problem was that you simply did not see the log output because you forgot the log configuration for your application package `com.demo.apiservice`:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework.web: DEBUG
      hibernate: DEBUG
    com:
      atoz_develop:
        mybatissample:
          repository: TRACE
      demo.apiservice: DEBUG
```

BTW, I also corrected your typo `hibernat` to `hibernate`, but that is unrelated to the problem at hand.

Then I see this in the log:

```
[  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[  restartedMain] c.d.a.ApiServiceApplication              : Started ApiServiceApplication in 5.101 seconds (JVM running for 6.117)
[  restartedMain] c.d.a.c.AopLoggingConfig                 : Controller     :  com.demo.apiservice.customer.CustomerController.@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ retrieveAll()
[  restartedMain] c.d.a.c.AopLoggingConfig                 : Controller     :  com.demo.apiservice.customer.CustomerController.@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ retrieveAll()
[  restartedMain] c.d.a.c.CustomerController               : Start of CustomerController::retrieveAll method
```

Do you see the problem? You get duplicate logging, because the aspect is picked up once by component scan and instantiated one more time as a bean in your application configuration. So you need to **remove** this part from `ApiServiceApplication`:

```java
  @Bean
  public AopLoggingConfig loggingAspect() {
    return new AopLoggingConfig();
  }
```

Now the duplicate logging is gone.

Next, maybe you want to simplify your aspect a bit and simply log `joinPoint` or `joinPoint.getSignature()`. You also want to make `name` and `type` local variables, because the static fields are not thread-safe. Instead, probably you want a static logger in the aspect.

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class AopLoggingConfig {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AopLoggingConfig.class);

  @Around("execution(* com.demo.apiservice.customer.*Controller.*(..))")
  public Object logPrint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    String type = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();
    String name = "";

    if (type.contains("Controller")) {
      name = "Controller  \t:  ";
    }
    else if (type.contains("Service")) {
      name = "ServiceImpl  \t:  ";
    }
    else if (type.contains("DAO")) {
      name = "DAO  \t\t:  ";
    }

    logger.debug(name + joinPoint.getSignature());
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

The log line becomes:

```
Controller      :  ResponseEntity com.demo.apiservice.customer.CustomerController.retrieveAll()
```

But actually, both the package name and the class name indicate that we are dealing with a controller, DAO or service. So why bother with the `if-else` stuff in the first place? Why make a simple matter complicated and the aspect slower? Besides, if you only want to log something and not influence the control flow, the method parameters or the return value, a simple `@Before` advice would do, the expensive `@Around` is unnecessary.

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class AopLoggingConfig {
  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AopLoggingConfig.class);

  @Before("execution(* com.demo.apiservice.customer.*Controller.*(..))")
  public void logPrint(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    logger.debug(joinPoint.getSignature().toString());
  }
}
```

The log line becomes:

```
ResponseEntity com.demo.apiservice.customer.CustomerController.retrieveAll()
```

Isn't that enough?

Or even simpler:

```java
    logger.debug(joinPoint.toString());
```

Log:

```
execution(ResponseEntity com.demo.apiservice.customer.CustomerController.retrieveAll())
```

Keep it simple!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I changed it and test it. it still didn't work.

Comment: Then you made a mistake while applying my changes to your own project. I tested my code, it works 100%. If you publish a minimal sample project on GitHub, I can take a look.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Here is the my gihhub url.
https://github.com/lee77840/demo

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you simply got your logging config wrong. In your GitHub project, the base package is not `demo.apiservice` like in the code you posted here, but simply `demo`. I.e., under `com:` you add the indented line `demo: DEBUG`, and you are going to see the log output. There is no AOP problem, there is a logging config problem only.

Comment: The source code I posted and the source code of Git are different.
I've edited my source and uploaded it to git so you can check it out.

Comment: I know, that's what I just said before. I already tried your GitHub project before writing my previous comment. Just do what I said and be happy. Don't make a simple matter complicated. Please read my comments more carefully, this is getting tiresome.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I resolved it.
Thank you so much.
Happy Thanksgiving All.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```java
package com.demo.apiservice.config;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class AopLoggingConfig {

    Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(AopLoggingConfig.class);

    static String name = "";

    static String type = "";

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void controllerClassMethods() {}

    @Around("controllerClassMethods()")
    public Object logPrint(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        type = joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName();

        if (type.indexOf("Controller")  -1) {
            name = "Controller  \t:  ";
        }
        else if (type.indexOf("Service")  -1) {
            name = "ServiceImpl  \t:  ";
        }
        else if (type.indexOf("DAO")  -1) {
            name = "DAO  \t\t:  ";
        }
        logger.debug(name + type + ".@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

This will match all the methods in all classes annotated with `@RestController`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I changed it and test it. it didn't work.